# No JWT created from JSON Web Tokens using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm using spring security and JSON Web Tokens for email verification.
I noticed that there is no JWT created when I register a new employee.
I use email for login, not username. I don't know if that problem with the Userdetalis interface.
when I'm trying to login into Postman, I get this error.
[image]

My code :

EmployeeController :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"})
@Tag(name = "Employee", description = "Employee API")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EmployeeController.BASE_URL)
public class EmployeeController {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "/api/v1/employees";
    private final EmployeeService employeeService;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;

@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
PasswordEncoder encoder;

@Autowired
JwtUtils jwtUtils;

public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService, ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
    this.confirmationTokenService = confirmationTokenService;
}

@GetMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public EmployeeListDTO getEmployeeList() {
    return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
}


@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDTO loginRequest) {
    System.out.println("Hei");

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    System.out.println("Hei2");

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
    System.out.println(jwt);

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
            userDetails.getId(),
            userDetails.getEmail(),
            roles));
}


@GetMapping({"/{id}"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public EmployeeDTO getEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
}

@PostMapping("/signup")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public EmployeeDTO createNewEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {
    return employeeService.createNewEmployee(employeeDTO);
}


@PutMapping({"/{id}"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public EmployeeDTO updateEmployee(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO){
    return employeeService.saveEmployeeByDTO(id, employeeDTO);
}

@DeleteMapping({"/{id}"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id){
    employeeService.deleteEmployeeDTO(id);
}
```

}

```
> package com.tietoevry.bookorabackend.security.jwt;
> 
> import com.tietoevry.bookorabackend.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
> import org.slf4j.Logger; import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; import
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import
> org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
> import
> org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
> import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
> import
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
> import org.springframework.util.StringUtils; import
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
> 
> import javax.servlet.FilterChain; import
> javax.servlet.ServletException; import
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; import
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; import java.io.IOException;
> 
> 
> public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
```

> ```
> @Autowired
> private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
>
> @Autowired
> private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
>
> private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);
>
> @Override
> protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
>
>         throws ServletException, IOException {
>
>     try {
>         String jwt = parseJwt(request);
>
>
>         if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
>             String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
>
>             UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
>             UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
>                     userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
>             authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
>
>             SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
>         } else {
>             System.out.println("No JWT yet");
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
>     }
>
>     filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
> }
>
> private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
>     String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
>
>     if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer")) {
>         return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
>     }
>
>     return null;
> } }
> ```

```
import java.util.List;

public class JwtResponse {
    private String token;
    private String type = "Bearer";
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private List<String> roles;

    public JwtResponse(String accessToken, Long id, String email, List<String> roles) {
        this.token = accessToken;
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.token = accessToken;
    }

    public String getTokenType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.type = tokenType;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
}
```

> ```
> //generate Token
> @Component
> public class JwtUtils {
>     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);
>
>     @Value("${bezkoder.app.jwtSecret}")
>     private String jwtSecret;
>
>     @Value("${bezkoder.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
>     private int jwtExpirationMs;
>
>     public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {
>
>         UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
>
>         return Jwts.builder()
>                 .setSubject((userPrincipal.getEmail()))
>                 .setIssuedAt(new Date())
>                 .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
>                 .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
>                 .compact();
>     }
>
>     public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
>         return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
>     }
>
>     public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
>         try {
>             Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
>             return true;
>         } catch (SignatureException e) {
>             logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
>         } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
>             logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
>         } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
>             logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
>         } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
>             logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
>         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
>             logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
>         }
>
>         return false;
>     }
> }
>
>
>
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
>         // securedEnabled = true,
>         // jsr250Enabled = true,
>         prePostEnabled = true)
> public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>     @Autowired
>     UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
>
>     @Autowired
>     private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
>
>     @Bean
>     public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
>         return new AuthTokenFilter();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
>         authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     @Override
>     public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
>         return super.authenticationManagerBean();
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
>         return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>
>
>
>         http.authorizeRequests()
>                 .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
>                 .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
>
>         http.csrf().disable();
>         http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
>         http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
>                 .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
>                 .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
>                 .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/employees/**").permitAll()
>                 .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
>                 .anyRequest().authenticated();
>
>         http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
>     }
> ```

and in intellj I get :

[image]

Comment: There looks like a warning from bcrypt related to encoded password. Is your password correctly encoded in the request?

Comment: Can you show us how the passwords look like in db, which version of security and user details service?